# Rails's Administrate - Sorting records in show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, administrate, rails-administrate

I have models named Conference, Attend and Delegate. A `Conference` has many `Delegate`s through `Attend` (*`Attend` is used as a join table*).

In `conference_dashboard.rb`:

```rb
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    id: Field::Number,
    attends: Field::HasMany 
  }.freeze

SHOW_PAGE_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
    attends
  ].freeze
```

In `attend_dashboard.rb`:

```rb
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    id: Field::Number,
    delegates: Field::BelongsTo,
    attended: Field::Boolean
  }.freeze

COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
    delegate
    attended
  ].freeze
```

Conference's show view looks like below: [image]

The question is: When I click on the sort link (highlighted in yellow), I want Attend records will be sorted based on `delegates.name`, not `delegates.id` (default). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the documentation for what you are looking for over here: https://administrate-demo.herokuapp.com/customizing_dashboards

It is possible to customize the dashboard and give options to it. In your case you need to update the `attend_dashboard.rb` to the following:

```rb
ATTRIBUTE_TYPES = {
    id: Field::Number,
    delegates: Field::BelongsTo.with_options(
        order: ['name']
    ),
    attended: Field::Boolean
  }.freeze

COLLECTION_ATTRIBUTES = %i[
    delegate
    attended
  ].freeze
```